# Consuming ASP.NET Web Api from Android HttpUrlConnection and Gson

Tags: android, asp.net, gson, httpurlconnection

Heyy everyone,
I'm trying to consume a web service from Android, I did that from my Java Desktop App and it worked fine but when I tried it on Android I had a lot of errors.
I already fixed the "localhost" problem with IIS express .
Please Help me with that.

```
public void SetCloud(View v) {

    ConnectionTask task = new ConnectionTask();

    try {
        task.execute().get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    /*
    Http http = HttpFactory.create(context);
    http.post("http://192.168.8.2:57888/api/Employees/AddAccount")
        .data(new AccountBag("Test123", "TestServer12","D19916F-7C51-4AD6-AC24"))
        .send();*/
}


private class ConnectionTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{
    String responseCode = null;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
      try {

        URL url = new URL("http://192.168.8.2:57888/api/Employees/AddAccount");
          //URL url = new URL("http://esprit.azurewebsites.net/api/comments");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");


        AccountBag obj = new AccountBag("Test123", "TestServer12","D19916F-7C51-4AD6-AC24"/*,"DateTime","aaa","bbbb","cccc","dddd","ffff"*/);
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        // convert java object to JSON format,
        // and returned as JSON formatted string
        String json = gson.toJson(obj);

        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        //os.write(input.getBytes());
        os.write(json.getBytes());
        os.flush();

        /*if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                + conn.getResponseCode());
        }*/
        responseCode = ""+conn.getResponseCode();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                (conn.getInputStream())));

        String output;
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
        }

        conn.disconnect();

      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

      } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

     }
    return responseCode;

    }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
               // result is what you got from your connection
//ConnectionTask.responseCode.setText(result);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class RestAddGroupUser extends AsyncTask<List<UserGroup>,Void,String> {
private  RestService lRestService;
private String url;
group_action activity;
ArrayList<LatLong> mParam;

public RestAddGroupUser(Activity activity) {
    url= GlobalData.baseURL + "AddGroupuser";
    this.activity = (group_action)activity;
}

protected void onPreExecute(){
}
String result = "";

protected String doInBackground(List<UserGroup>... params) {

    try {

        StringEntity en;
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String jsonobj=gson.toJson(params[0]);
        jsonobj=jsonobj.substring(1, jsonobj.length()-1);
        en= new StringEntity(jsonobj,"UTF-8");
        en.setContentType("application/json");

        // Add parameters
        httppost.setEntity(en);
        String jsonobject=gson.toJson(params[1]);
        jsonobject=jsonobject.substring(1, jsonobj.length()-1);
        en= new StringEntity(jsonobject,"UTF-8");
        en.setContentType("application/json");

        // Add parameters
        httppost.setEntity(en);
        httppost = ServiceUtils.SetPostRequestHeader(httppost,activity);

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity != null) {
            InputStream inStream = entity.getContent();
            result = convertStreamToString(inStream);
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
public void onPostExecute(String result){

    Gson gson =new Gson();
    boolean status = false;


}
public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is){
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;

    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

}

Comment: Can you explain me a little bit the code because i couldn't understand it like the "<List<UserGroup>" utility or RestAddGroupUser Function I really didn't get anything

Comment: let me know the request and response parameter

Comment: I'm going to post data (by data I mean "AccountBag" Class content) as it is written in the code and for the response I'm just returning the response Code to know if it the data was transmitten or not :)

Comment: @HediJl In my code sample  **url= GlobalData.baseURL + "AddGroupuser";**  is service url and **List<UserGroup>** class that to be used as a input parameter. and return type is boolean on onPostExecute method